# Child component updates parent state unexpectedly in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-state

I'm using react with MUI. I'm using the MUI List component which each list may have a nested list in it. the problem is when I open a nested list, the parent component gets closed. I don't know what I am doing wrong. You could use this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-forked-b52i2k).

Here is an image of my app: [Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEWh.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you add `onClick` on `ListItem` which contains all other sub-items, so that means whenever you trigger click on any sub-item, you accidentally trigger the main `ListItem` too. That's why you've seen the main menu item gets collapsed when you click on any sub-item. You can read more about [event propagation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e/).

The easiest fix is you should move `onClick={handleToggleCollapse}` from `ListItem` to `ListItemButton`

```
<ListItem {...listItemProps} sx={{ display: "block" }}>
      <ListItemButton onClick={handleToggleCollapse}>
        {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
        {open ? (
          <IoIosArrowUp className="text-lg" />
        ) : (
          <IoIosArrowDown className="text-lg" />
        )}
      </ListItemButton>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout={300}>
        <List disablePadding>
          <ListItems listItems={nestedItems} />
        </List>
      </Collapse>
</ListItem>
```

For event propagation prevention, you should modify `handleToggleCollapse` like below

```
  function handleToggleCollapse(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  }
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-forked-b3vleq?file=/src/components/SideBar/ListItems/CollapsibleListItem/useCollapsibleListItem.ts:134-245)